# How to setup ASP Classic and ASP.NET WebForm in the same visual studio solution - for rewriting ASP Classic pages in ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, vbscript, asp-classic

I'll be working on in a project where we'll be re-writing ASP classic pages to ASP.NET WebForm. I've never worked with VB, VBScript, ASP Classic. The good thing is there are plenty of documentation on VB6, VB.NET, ASP Classic, and even on how to migrate ASP to ASP.NET WebForm.

Although in all the tutorial it's said that the best strategy to re-write  an existing ASP classic application in ASP.NET WebForm is to integrate them in one solution then move chunk of code at a time, I can't find one tutorial where it's shown how to set up a Visual Studio solution with both ASP and ASP.NET WebForm code.

so how do I setup a Visual Studio solution with both types of application? At least point me to such tutorial.

Thanks for helping

Comment: In my experience, there's no such thing as "migrating classic ASP to ASP.NET" (whatever tutorials promise). The two technologies are fundamentally different and ASP.NET is just the pipeline - what framework would you use: forms or MVC? Classic ASP is just a series of `Response.Write`-s - this is possible in ASP.NET but it gives you suboptimal code (from all angles) and you'll skip all advanced features by doing this. Spend some time considering if migration is really what you want - you'll spend about the same time "migrating" than if you just rewrite the application from scratch.

Comment: @xxbbcc excuse my ignorance. Actually, the goal is not to migrate the application per se. The activities in that project will consist in re-writing the application. I keep calling it migration because that's what I found in the literature. I guess I need to modify the content of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that in Solution Explorer you right click on the project root, select Add -> Existing Item, and then add your .asp files to the project.  You may already have some files which have nothing to do with .net in your project, such as stylesheets and image files, treat .asp files in the same way. Beyond that there's no additional setup required

Classic ASP code isn't compiled, it's intepreted at runtime, so you won't be able to debug them the way you would with C#/VB.net files within VS, the standard way to debug Classic ASP is via error messages when you try run the page.  When you have a mixture of Classic and .net I find it helps to see them as two separate websites which live in the same root folder.

Also, in case you haven't discovered this already, the dev server which comes with VS doesn't support Classic ASP, so you need to set your project up to use a local version of IIS (or IIS Express) as your dev server

Comment: FYI: it is possible to debug Classic ASP similarly to ASP.NET applications. Check out https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/debugging-classic-asp-with-visual-studio-2013 for details. This may prove helpful when analyzing the behavior of the older system you are rewriting.